# Is there a way to have mysql pass root password?

Tags: mysql, linux, passwords

When I'm logged into Linux as root (or sudo), I thought when I typed mysql that MySQL used the current username and password of the Linux user, however, when I try that, it just gives error ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). I don't want to disable requiring a password, I just want it passed from the current user if they're not specified (I've already disabled anonymous users too).

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pam-authentication-plugin.html

Comment: Please do not log in as root. Do as little as possible as root. Then you will not go far wrong

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That would be great as an actual answer. if you're willing to post it, I'll happily upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify the username, MySQL on Linux uses the username of the calling process, but *not* the password belonging to that user.

The password of the caller is not available to applications on Linux, and I think this is for the best!

By default, MySQL authenticates against an internal table of users and passwords that has nothing to do with the operating system's passwd file. The fact that MySQL instances often have a user called 'root' is coincidence; the MySQL 'root' is not the same as the Linux 'root', and they can (and should) have different passwords.

If you want to avoid the requirement to type a password every time, you should save a default user/password in `$HOME/.my.cnf`:

```
[client]
user = scott
password = tiger
```

(I recommend against storing the superuser password in this file.)

In MySQL 5.6, they introduces a new feature to store login credentials more securely. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the option AllowNoPassword on file /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php.

Edit the file config.inc.php, search and uncomment this line:

*// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;*

**if it's set to false make it true and restart the Mysql Service** and you are good to go

Then you can access PhpMyAdmin/MySQl Console without password.

Answer (score 0):

just put an alias in your .bashrc:

```
alias mysql="mysql -u root -pYourPassWord"
```